# changing ip using visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

im trying to change my ip using visual basic
i'm pretty new to Visual Basic, actually i'm barely use it.
i have a small project for the university that i need but i can't get it done.
hope you guys can show some light in the dark.

this is my code:

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim IPAddress As String = (TextBox1.Text)
        Dim SubnetMask As String = (TextBox2.Text)
        Dim Gateway As String = (TextBox3.Text)

        Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
        Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()

        For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
            If (Not CBool(objMO("IPEnabled"))) Then
                Continue For
            End If

            Try
                Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing

                objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
                objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")

                'Set DefaultGateway
                objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {Gateway}
                objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

                'Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {IPAddress}
                objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {SubnetMask}

                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)

                Console.WriteLine("Updated IPAddress, SubnetMask and Default Gateway!")

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to Set IP : " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next objMO
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            getip()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ex.ToString()
        End Try

        Dim PrimaryNic As New Collection
        Dim PNic As String = ""
        For Each networkCard As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
            For Each gatewayAddr As GatewayIPAddressInformation In networkCard.GetIPProperties.GatewayAddresses
                If gatewayAddr.Address.ToString <> "0.0.0.0" And networkCard.OperationalStatus.ToString() = "Up" Then
                    Dim IpAddress As UnicastIPAddressInformation

                    For Each IpAddress In networkCard.GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses
                        TextBox2.Text = (IpAddress.IPv4Mask.ToString)
                    Next
                    ' Get IP gateway information  
                    TextBox3.Text = (gatewayAddr.Address.ToString)
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub getip()
        Dim hostname As String = Dns.GetHostName
        Dim ip As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(hostname).AddressList(0).ToString

        TextBox1.Text = ip
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see i made 3 textboxs that retrieve the Static IP, Subnet Mask and Gateway from the components.
That way if computer has other data than 192.168 it'll work on it too.

But it doesn't work, when i press the button it's not even thinking. just nothing happen.

i have also tried to run it from a batch file, it didn't work as well. It changed that ip (to the specific one in the batch file, but the internet connection stopped working)

i'm testing it on a Virtual Machine (windows 7) that i have, i didn't want to screw my connection if something will go wrong. (i don't know if it matter that im testing it on VM or not)

Hope you can help me
Many Thanks!